# org-priority and org-insert-structure-template key binding clash

Tags: org-mode

I'm using or-mode 9.2 and when I hit `C-c C-,` and I got the following message:

```
Before first headline at position 480 in buffer index.org
```

The message indicates that the key actually get translated as `C-c ,`, which maps to `org-priority`. I turn on `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and see the following when I press `C-c C-,`

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Before first headline at position 470 in buffer index.org")
  signal(error ("Before first headline at position 470 in buffer index.org"))
  error("Before first headline at position %d in buffer %s" 470 #<buffer index.org>)
  org-back-to-heading(t)
  org-priority(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-priority nil)
  call-interactively(org-priority nil nil)
  command-execute(org-priority)
```

Does anyone run into issue like this?

Comment: What is the contents of the buffer (and where is the cursor) where you see this error?

Comment: And what does this have to do with org-insert-structure or a key binding clash?

Comment: @DanRobertson: `C-c C-,` is bound to `org-insert-structure-template` by default (in recent versions of Org mode, certainly after 9.0 but possibly later). OP: is this in GUI emacs or in terminal emacs?

Comment: @NickD I'm using emacs 26.3 in iTerm2 on a Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Macs or iTerm2, but running emacs in a terminal will sometimes cause problems like this. E.g. I work on Linux under X with a GUI emacs, but if I start an `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` and run `emacs -nw` in it, the key `C-,` does not exist: if I hold down the `Control` key and press `,` what I get is just `,`. This is probably what you are running into.

In GUI Emacs under X, the window system allows emacs to synthesize keys: it knows that you pressed down the `Control` key and then you pressed down `,` so emacs can pretend that it saw a `C-,`.

Try it: say `C-h c C-,` - if you try this in GUI emacs, it will most probably say `C-, is undefined` because most modes don't define it. But note that it actually saw a `C-,`. If you try the same thing in your terminal emacs, it'll say `, runs the command self-insert-command`: it does not know that you pressed the `Control` key; it only sees the comma.

What to do? You can run GUI emacs instead; or you can bind `org-insert-structure-template` to some key that you *can* press - function keys might be useful here, because terminal emacs (at least xterm and gnome-terminal on linux - YMMV) recognizes not just the bare key (e.g. F1), but also modified versions: `S-F1` is known as `<f13>` (there are usually twelve function keys on standard US keyboards) and `C-F1` is known as `<f25>`. You can check these things out with the `C-h c` trick above.

So you can try something like this:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f25>") 'org-insert-structure-template)
```

Then pressing `C-F1` would invoke the `org-insert-structure-template` command.